# How to get the code coverage from the Postman tests?

Tags: java, jersey, code-coverage, dropwizard

We are using jersey-client for rest in dropwizard framework.
I need to get the report of the code coverage but the tests are written in postman.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you have a Postman collection that is run against your server?

Comment: It seems like you want something like this, but for java:
https://github.com/matthiasnoback/live-code-coverage
Unfortunately I don't know of anything for java.